# Trying to count the number of integers $x \le n$ where gcd$\left(x(x+2),30\right)=1$ using the möbius function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, mobius-function

Let:

- $x>0, n >0$ be integers
- gcd$(s,t)$ be the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of $s$ and $t$
- $\mu(x)$ be the [möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function)

For $x \le n$ and gcd$(x,30)=1$, the count is:

$$\sum_{i | 30}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor\mu(i) = n - \left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{n}{5}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{n}{6}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{n}{10}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor\frac{n}{15}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{n}{30}\right\rfloor$$

For $x \le 30$ and gcd$\left(x(x+2\right),30)=1$, the count is:

$$30 - \left\lfloor\frac{30}{2}\right\rfloor - 2\left\lfloor\frac{30}{3}\right\rfloor - 2\left\lfloor\frac{30}{5}\right\rfloor + 2\left\lfloor\frac{30}{6}\right\rfloor + 2\left\lfloor\frac{30}{10}\right\rfloor +2\left\lfloor\frac{30}{15}\right\rfloor=3$$

I am not clear how to represent this using the möbius function.

I had expected this to work:

$$\sum_{i|30}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor\mu(i) + \sum_{i|30\text{ and }i>2}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor\mu(i)$$

It does not work for $n=30$.  I am not clear why, in this case, $-2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{30}\right\rfloor$ is not needed.

How do you correctly count the integers $x \le n$ where gcd$\left(x(x+1),30\right)=1$ using the möbius function?

---

Edit:

rtybase makes a good point.  This can be precisely calculated using:

$$\left\lfloor\frac{n+19}{30}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{n+13}{30}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{30}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: I'd go with simple steps like one of $\{x,x+1\}$ is divisible by $2$, so it should be $x+1$. One of $\{x,x+1,x+2\}$ is divisible by $3$, so it should be $x+1$. So $6 \mid x+1$, or $\gcd(36k^2 -1,30)=1$

Comment: That's pretty much what I am trying to do.  :-)  I am not clear how to generalize the examples you mention to the case of $x(x+2)$ which suggests a logic of  $2$ of $[x, x+1, x+2]$ when multiplied by $(x+2)$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: It reduces to finding $k$'s s.t. $\gcd(36k^2 -1, 30)=1$. Or easier, $36k^2 -1 \ne 5t$.

Comment: Yes, all such $x$ would have the form $30x+11$, $30x+17$ or $30x+29$.  :-)  How would you calculate the count of such numbers less than $n$ precisely.  It is roughly $\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{10}\right\rfloor$  I am looking for a precise calculation.

Comment: Looks like $\left[\frac{n-11}{30}\right] + \left[\frac{n-17}{30}\right]+\left[\frac{n-29}{30}\right]$ is the answer. I can't think of any other, more precise answer.

Comment: Thanks!  I think you are right.  That's exactly what I was looking for!  :-)